# Misspelling in bounties tab

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties, spelling

The tab with bounties says 'bountied' instead of 'bounties':

[image]

Answer (score 13):

'Bountied' is used as an adjective here; you should think of the tabs as the following list, but with the word 'questions' omitted:

- Newest questions
- Active questions
- Bountied questions
- Unanswered questions
- More tabs (OK, that's the odd one out)

You won't find this usage in [most dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bounty) but English is known for constructions like this; this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

[image]

Note that the URL parameter does say `bounties`: https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=bountied doesn't do what you'd expect, it ends up in the Active tab. The old URL, https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured, is still working for backward compatibility reasons.

Comment: Maybe use *stuff* instead of *questions* ... that works for *More* as well ...

Comment: @rene or *problems* ...